# Sign of Firebase's clock skew

Tags: java, clock, firebase

Firebase's [docs about presence](https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-presence.html) say that the "client's clock skew" is a value "that Firebase will add to the local reported time (epoch time in milliseconds) to estimate the server time".

Then, in the examples, it says for example:

```
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
     double offset = snapshot.getValue(Double.class);
     double estimatedServerTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis() + offset;
 }
```

On one Android device that I use for testing, I have changed the clock so that it fast by 4 minutes (roughly). Now when I get the clock skew via the Java SDK, the value I get is the following:

```
232599.0
```

As this is in milliseconds, it corresponds to `3.87665` minutes.

But to get an estimation for the server's time, I would have to *add* it to the local timestamp (`System.currentTimeMillis()`). Is that right?

If the client's clock is already fast by 4 minutes, and I *add* those 3.9 minutes, don't I get an estimation that is fast by about 8 minutes?

By the way, it would be perfect if I could use the server timestamp in `setPriority()`. Currently, `ServerValue.Timestamp` is only available for `setValue()` as it is not a primitive value. As I want to use the time in `setPriority()`, I have to calculate the server's time by using `System.currentTimeMillis()` and the clock skew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the offset to determine the localized time relative to the server.

Thus, if you get a server time for 08:05 your client is 10 minutes fast, then the clock on the client's machine reads 08:15 at the client (08:05 + 00:10 minutes).

If you want to revert a time without using ServerValue.Timestamp, then you would subtract, which would take a client time and make it match the server (e.g. 08:15 - 00:10 = 08:05).

This is how I did it in projects before ServerValue.Timestamp was introduced and it worked spiffy.

Comment: Yes, thank you :) This is what I'm doing as well, but don't you see how it is wrong in `onDataChange()` that I have cited from the docs? They essentially do `estimatedServerTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis() + offset` which is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: By the way, when using `ServerValue.Timestamp`, you cannot specify the key yourself, did I get this right? Its type is `java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>` and thus something like the following is not possible in Java: https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/servervalue/TIMESTAMP.html

Comment: Marco, if the server time (right now) is 8:04 am and you parse that on the client, which is 4 mins fast, you'll get 8:04 am (four minutes ago); you must add 4 to make it 8:08 (right now). I've talked to the Firebase devs about the setPriority() bug and they're going to roll a fix for that.

Comment: Also, testing out the Java client, it looks like the sign is wrong; so  when you run this test as it shows in the example, you're getting the opposite result! The dev team has been notified about that, too.

Comment: Okay, great :) Thank you! So the sign of the clock skew is indeed wrong, as I was asking, and it's not just that I'm bad at arithmetics, right? :) I didn't find where to report that Java SDK specific bug and as they say free plans have only community support, I tried it here.

Comment: And with the "setPriority() bug", you are referring to the problem that you cannot use `ServerValue.Timestamp` with setPriority()? So I don't have to report those bugs to the Firebase team anymore, right?

Comment: Marco, that's correct. I've reported them and had a chat with the team. They're queued for an upcoming release.